# Is it possible to customize how spring parses query parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've been using a generic map for query parameters in a spring-boot (4.3.3.RELEASE) application, which has been live and taking traffic for a while now. This application has dozens of different endpoints and recently I've seen that a number requests result in errors due to improperly formatted query parameters.

I've been seeing a significant number of the requests are coming through like `http://web.com/url/path?param1=1?param2=2`. Unfortunately, I don't control or know why these urls are showing up, and they are all resulting in error pages for the users using them.

Can spring be customized to parse maps of query parameters using both '&' and '?' as separators?

I suspect this can be supported with a custom interceptor to inspect modify the incoming urls, but I wanted to know if there is an easier solution.

This is an example the one endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url/path", method = {GET, POST})
public ResponseEntity<Void> handleRequest(
    @RequestHeader HttpHeaders requestHeaders,
    @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams) throws Exception
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: There is a way to do this which is **not recommended** though, using [httpServletRequest.getQueryString()]( https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString ), in this way you'll get everything after the first interceptor which should be ?.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would be a not recommended solution.